# Redux-saga preload data on route change

Tags: redux, react-router, redux-saga

I want to load a set of data from an api using redux-saga but I can't find an example of how to do this when navigating to a new route (eg /posts) before rendering the route.

How would I do this?

Comment: Are you intending on waiting before the route change for the request to complete, during, or after?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I am also looking for that, I have found this project : https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-router/ but the project doesn't seems really supported

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onEnter` prop on `Route`:

```
<Route path='posts' onEnter={() => store.dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS' })} />
```

In this case, you can't use the store in the context of the tree that is inserted in `Provider`. You'd have to import it and use directly.

Another option is instead of passing a `component` prop, pass a `getComponent`:

```
<Route path='posts' getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
  store.dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS' });
  cb(null, PostList);
}} />
```

I can't tell what are the pros/cons for any of those approaches though since I've never used them. I just tried to find a solution that could work for your use case.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a call to fetch data when the new component mounts. For this to work you need to write the component so that it can at least partially render with incomplete data.